# In Spring Boot, can I configure a Controller (or Handler) without using Annotations?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

In Spring Boot 2, Is there a way to configure a Controller (aka Handler) without using annotations like `@Controller` or `@RestController` in the controller classes? Instead I would like to define it in Java Config.

OR

Is there a way to configure the Path `GET "/v1/test/myapi" mycontroller::myapi()` in a `@Configuration` bean instead of defining them in the Controller?

My use case is, I have test & live versions of REST APIs (similar to that of Stripe or Lob - where our customers can test APIs before going live on their end), which will have same contracts, but underlying wirings to Service beans are different. Now I do not want to create two Controller classes with different wirings.

I want to configure:

```
1. (ControllerA) object1 -> ServiceA -> RepositoryA
2. (ControllerA) object2 -> ServiceB -> RepositoryB
```

I am unable to do this configuration without defining ControllerB in (2).

Thanks!

Note: To understand `live` vs `test`, pls. refer here - https://lob.com/resources/guides/accounts/test-and-live-environments (caveat - this is just a reference - I don't work for Lob)

Comment: First of all you should not be writing a separate Controller, Service and Repository just for testing. There should be a separate test environment to do the testing that is different from production.

Comment: did you consider extracting an interface out of your service and use profiles to enable either serviceA or serviceB? is this just for local testing or are these different deployments?

Comment: Arun, you want the controller to differ from ServiceA to ServiceB during run time or it should go to ServiceB only in case of test like when your are running the install phase?

Comment: @royalghost I have edited my question. When I say test - it is not test (unit/system) of the APIs. It is test version of the APIs for our customers.

Comment: @ArunAvanathan You should be using something else, like asking user to add request header `env:test` based on the request header you can choose ServiceA or B.

Comment: @wemu Profiles are useful between environments. In my case both test & live versions need to run in the same spring container at the same time.

Comment: Your last comment makes no sense at all. You wouldn't be able to map multiple controllers to the same endpoints anyway. The industry-standard way to do this is to either (1) have a different "test" base endpoint or (2) have "test" credentials (like Stripe's 4242... card numbers) and route them _inside_ your services. You could do this easily with a Composite pattern facade over your service backend.

Comment: (In the case of the link you provided, what's almost certainly happening is that a service gateway at the very front is checking your credentials and then routing requests to different copies of the servers on the backend for the different environments.)

Comment: @chrylis agreed. I my case, we'll do that using zuul in front & route the requests to either test or live based on the API keys. For short term, I wanted a simplistic approach where I can do the same in a single cluster.

Comment: I bumped into this example in Functional web https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-web. Eg. `route(GET("/employees/{id}") ..` in Java config.
What I am asking is configuring above in Java config for traditional (non functional) controllers.